# How do i get my Beautiful soup output data to a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, beautifulsoup

How do i get my Beautiful soup output data to a text file?
Here's the code;

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib2.urlopen("http://link").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(url)

file = open("parseddata.txt", "wb")

for line in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'book-title-link'}):

 print (line.get('href'))

 file.write(line.get('href'))

 file.flush()

 file.close()
```

Comment: `file.flush()` and `file.close()` should be outside of for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file.close` should be called once (after the `for` loop):

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urllib2.urlopen("http://link").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
file = open("parseddata.txt", "wb")
for line in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'book-title-link'}):
    href = line.get('href')
    print href
    if href:
        file.write(href + '\n')
file.close()
```

**UPDATE** you can use `href=True` to avoid `if` statement. In addition to it, using [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), you don't need to close the file object manually:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


content = urllib2.urlopen("http://link").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

with open('parseddata.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'book-title-link'}, href=True):
        print a['href']
        f.write(a['href'] + '\n')
```

Comment: You cannot add None and a string, if .get returns None it would probably be better to ignore it altogether

Comment: @PadraicCunningham,  I updated the answer according to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, you could also set href=True

Answer (score 0):

I just do this:

```
with open('./output/' + filename + '.html', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(temp.prettify("utf-8"))
```

temp is the html that is prased by beautifulsoup.